# add spacing between div elements

Tags: html, image, spacing

I would like to add spacing between these div elements. 
How can I do that?

```html
<div style="clear: left;">
  <p class="image"><img src="https://blog.proven.com/wp-content/uploads/zipsqaure.jpg" height="200" width="200" border="1px"></p>
  <p class="rating"><strong><font size="4">Proven Rating: <font color="#0077b3">★★★★★</font></font></strong></p>
  <p class="description">ZipRecruiter allows employers to post jobs within minutes and reach over 200 million active job seekers. </p>
</div>

<div style="clear: left;">
  <p class="image"><img src="https://blog.proven.com/wp-content/uploads/snag-1.png" height="200" width="200" border="1px"></p>
  <p class="rating"><strong><font size="4">Proven Rating: <font color="#0077b3">★★★★★</font></font></strong></p>
  <p class="description">Snagajob allows employers to reach over 80 million job seekers through their job board. It was founded in 1999 and continues to be one of the top job boards today, hosting one of the largest hourly employee networks on the web.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What "spacing" means? Maybe margin?

Comment: Do you want space between the two divs, or space between all elements inside the divs?

Comment: Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin

Comment: Its good practice to add individual classes to the elements you want to style rather than using nested selectors which can get you into specificity traps https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/